# Getting "curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)"

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, rest, curl, cloudflare

I have a Django app which returns a large JSON while calling an API.
The problem is when I'm requesting the data, the data itself is truncated which is crashing the frontend.

I'm using cloud front for DNS and SSL and other feature provided by them for caching and improved performance.

I tried curling the API and got the following error from curl:

> curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err
> 2)

I tried disabling the Cloudflare but didn't work. On my localhost, however, everything works fine.

> HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)
>
> - Closing connection 0
> - TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1): curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

The JSON should be fetched entirely without getting chunked.

Comment: Fixed by setting proxy_buffering to false in nginx

Answer (score 34):

I got the same error with an application behind an AWS Application Load Balancer, using command:

```
curl "https://console.aws.example/api/xxx" -b "SESSION=$SESSION"
```

> 15:14:30 curl: (92) HTTP/2 stream 1 was not closed cleanly:
> PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)

I had to force the use of **HTTP/1.1** with the argument `--http1.1`

So the final command is:

```
curl "https://console.aws.example/api/xxx" -b "SESSION=$SESSION" --http1.1
```

Comment: This works! many thanks!, but now instead of the curl error message I get "Service unavailable" ...o_O

Comment: and also sometimes I still get the old error message ;/ - I use uvicorn, on the server, but not sure if I configured it correctly (I use curl to test my server)

Comment: Can this curl issue also be triggered by insufficient computational resources?

Answer (score 19):

I had this issue with AWS's Application Load Balancer (ALB). The problem was that I had Apache configured to use http2, but behind an ALB. The ALB supports http2 by default:

> Application Load Balancers provide native support for HTTP/2 with HTTPS listeners. You can send up to 128 requests in parallel using one HTTP/2 connection. The load balancer converts these to individual HTTP/1.1 requests and distributes them across the healthy targets in the target group. Because HTTP/2 uses front-end connections more efficiently, you might notice fewer connections between clients and the load balancer. You can’t use the server-push feature of HTTP/2. [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#listener-configuration)

So, curl was using HTTP/2 to connect with the ALB, which was then converting it into an HTTP/1 request. Apache was adding headers to the response asking the client to `Upgrade` to HTTP/2, which the ALB just passed back to the client, and curl read it as invalid since it was already using an HTTP/2 connection. I solved the problem by disabling HTTP/2 on my Apache instance. Since it will always be behind an ALB, and the ALB is never going to make use of HTTP/2, then there is no point of having it.

Comment: After hours debugging an error of a curl call to an NLB, I finally found out that it was due to HTTP/2 being disabled on my backend server. Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer is amazing! After many hours debugging I stumbled on this post which seems to be the most accurate explanation. In our case, we are using Google Project Shield for Content Delivery of our AWS EB + LB, but the CDN was not respecting the Upgrade header from the origin as the CDN only sends HTTP/1.1, which caused this to sometimes throw an error in Safari which now defaults to HTTP/2. Thank you!!

Answer (score 9):

Fix or Remove the `Content-Length` header in your HTTP request.

I was trying to connect to an AWS Gateway when this issue occurred to me. I was able to get the correct response using POSTMAN but if I copied over the same headers to `curl`, it would give me this error.

What finally worked for me was removing the `Content-Length` header as the length of the request in `curl` wasn't matching the same as it was in POSTMAN.

Since in my case I was only testing the API so this is fine, but I wouldn't suggest removing this header in production. Check to make sure the length is calculated correctly if this is occurring to you in a codebase.

Answer (score 1):

With Nginx, you can experience this error in curl by having two http2 virtual hosts listening on the same server name. Running a check on your nginx config file will throw a warning letting you know that something isn't right. Fixing/removing the duplicate listing fixes this problem.

```
# nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on [::]:443, ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

On my side issue was in the response header `"Upgrade"=h2,h2c`.
For example, extended response from curl -v:

```
* http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [upgrade], value: [h2,h2c]
* HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)
* stopped the pause stream!
```

I set this header empty `Upgrade: ""` and curl on http2 started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me what solved it was to set ssl sec level to 1.
See CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST